# Is it possible to connect a raspberry pi to an apple cinema display?

Tags: hdmi, pi-2, connection

I have an old apple cinema display, which has firewire and usb inputs. Is there anyway to connect the pi 2 to this? I have looked and I can't find any cheap solutions so I am planning on purchasing a small dedicated monitor but I want to double check before doing so. I have included a picture of the connections in the monitor

[image: Monitor connections]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not mention the OS, so I'll presume it's Raspbian or some other linux variant.

This depends on whether that display can really use a USB for *video input*.  I don't have one, so I'm not promising anything, but there is a USB driver for Apple Cinema displays included in the default kernel.<sup>1</sup>  However, I think it is just for using the USB as a control line for the backlight.

If you plug it in via USB presumably this will load; afterward check with:

```
lsmod | grep apple
```

If nothing shows up, check to make sure it is listed with `lsusb` (you will have to `apt-get install usbutils` first).  If it is listed, try `sudo modprobe appledisplay`;<sup>1</sup> if that succeeds look at:

```
tail -n 25 /var/log/syslog
```

There probably will be some indication that the driver found the display.

Even if this does work for video and not just backlight control, this will not work as a boot display unless you recompile the kernel, since as is it must mount the root filesystem before it can load the driver.

---

1. Here are the USB product ID's listed in the driver source as working:

   - 9218
   - 9219
   - 921c
   - 921d
   - 9236

You can find these via `lsusb` (which is in the `usbutils` package); the second one is the product ID and the first one will probably be 05ac (for Apple Inc.), e.g. `05as:921c`.  Finding the ID does not require a driver and you should be able to get it one way or the other on any computer with any mainstream OS.

Comment: I haven't installed the OS yet as I don't have access to a monitor but I have a card with NOOBs on it atm. What connection would I use to connect to the USB? I was under the impression USB-HDMI wasn't a thing?

Comment: In your photograph there are very clearly two USB jacks.  Use a USB-to-USB cable.  There is such a thing as USB-HDMI but it works *from* USB *to* HDMI.  I.e., you can't plug this into the pi's HDMI jack.

Comment: Can the pi use the usb ports for its display? I just assumed it had to go through the HDMI

Comment: You can run a USB display -- just I am sure it is going to be more hassle, because as far as I know you can't, as mentioned, use it as the boot display, by which I mean the one initialized by the hardware when it turns on then used initially by the OS.  However,  once you have it figured out, you could set it up as the primary/only display so that the GUI login is there (since that is arranged after the root filesystem is mounted and drivers can be loaded).  But to get to that point you probably need to use something else to set things up, which may take some work.

Comment: Ok so I would need to get a monitor to get myself going first. Thanks for your help

Comment: Really? Cinema Displays can be driven via USB? Seems too cool to be real... I guess you mean sth like a USB3 external video card to HDMI/DVI? USB2 is really too slow for that job...

Comment: @Gotschi Again, I don't have one; I *presumed* it could be used that way because the OP referred to "firewire and usb inputs" and clearly in the picture the only thing connected is USB.  Of course, the other end of the cable is not shown. You are right that USB 2.0 is supposed to be so-so for graphical displays, and on the pi this will be hampered further if you are using an internet connection via either USB or ethernet (since the latter shares the former's bus). That driver doesn't have documentation, but looking closer at it I think perhaps it is just for controlling the backlight (edited).

Answer (score 1):

I connect my raspberry pi to my apple cinema display using the "Kanex XD HDMI to Mini Displayport Converter". You need to connect up all the cables and start your pi in SAFE mode by holding down the shift key when that option appears on the screen. In safe mode you can edit the config file to set hdmi_group=1 to ensure you are outputting hdmi format. You also need to set hdmi_mode=4 the 720p resolution.  Save the config file and reboot your pi. The screen should work now, but not at its native high resolution. This is the best I have been able to do so far, but at least it works and my old cinema display is getting some use.

If you can't get the option to hold the shift key to start in safe mode, unplug the hdmi cable from the pi, unplug the pi power, plug the pi power back in, quickly plug the hdmi cable back into the pi. Be ready to press the shift key when the message appears. Not elegant, but it does work.